# Friend class not able to access private data

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, g++

Here is my class declaration:

```
template <class T>
class Sptr {
    template<typename U> friend class Sptr;

    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    friend bool operator==(const Sptr<T1> &a, const Sptr<T2> &b);

    template <typename U>
    friend Sptr<T> static_pointer_cast(const Sptr<U> &sp);

private:

    RC* ref; //reference counter
    T* obj;//pointer to current obj
    std::function<void()> destroyData;

    bool ok_;

public:

    Sptr();
    ~Sptr();

    template <typename U> 
    Sptr(U *);

    Sptr(const Sptr &);

    template <typename U> 
    Sptr(const Sptr<U> &);

    template <typename U> 
    Sptr<T> &operator=(const Sptr<U> &);

    Sptr<T> &operator=(const Sptr<T> &);

    void reset();

    T* operator->() const
    {return obj;};

    T& operator*() const
    {return *obj;};

    T* get() const
    {return obj;};

    explicit operator bool() const {
          return ok_;
    }

};
```

Below is the code thats complaining of access problem

```
    template <typename T, typename U>
Sptr<T> static_pointer_cast(const Sptr<U> &sp) {
    //do something
    Sptr<U> answer;

    answer.obj = sp.obj;
    answer.ref = sp.ref;
    answer.destroyData = sp.destroyData;
    answer.ok_ = sp.ok_;

    return answer;
}
```

when I compile with the following code:

```
    Sptr<Derived> sp(new Derived);
    Sptr<Base1> sp2(sp);

    // Sptr<Derived> sp3(sp2); // Should give a syntax error.
    Sptr<Derived> sp3(static_pointer_cast<Derived>(sp2));
    // Sptr<Derived> sp4(dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(sp2)); // Should give syntax error about polymorphism.
```

I have already made it a friend function. Why is it not able to access the variables and how to correct it?

Comment: Two minor tips which don't have anything to do with your problem: You shouldn't put semicolon after a function implementation. And you can make the `operator==` a member and it thus doesn't have to be a friend.

Comment: Either it's a copy-paste error when you wrote your question or an error in your code: In the implementation of `static_pointer_cast` you're actually copying an `Sptr<U>` to an `Sptr<U>` which is then cast to `Sptr<T>` in the return statement. Did you want to allocate a `Sptr<T>` and then copy each field?

Comment: `template<typename U> friend class Sptr;` != `template <typename T, typename U> Sptr<T> static_pointer_cast(const Sptr<U> &sp)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit tricky. Your code compiles if you replace

```
template <typename U>
friend Sptr<T> static_pointer_cast(const Sptr<U> &sp);
```

with

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
friend Sptr<T1> static_pointer_cast(const Sptr<T2> &sp);
```

The reason is the following (I am not 100% sure, so please someone approve / dis-approve):

When `Sptr<T>` is instantiated, e.g. with `T = Derived`, the resulting class definition (`Sptr<Derived>`) defines a friend function having the following signature:

```
template <typename U>
friend Sptr<Derived> static_pointer_cast(const Sptr<U> &sp);
```

So this is a function which only has **one** template parameter. But the function you defined has **two** template parameters.

Your *call* to this templated function is a specialization which looks like this:

```
Sptr<Derived> static_pointer_cast(const Sptr<Base1> &sp) {
    //do something
    Sptr<Derived> answer;

    answer.obj = sp.obj;
    answer.ref = sp.ref;
    answer.destroyData = sp.destroyData;
    answer.ok_ = sp.ok_;

    return answer;
}
```

So it tries to access *both* `Base1` *and* `Derived`, but it's only a friend of `Derived`, not of `Base1`. This last sentence is the important thing, and changing it to a friend function with *two* template parameters solves this issue.

Comment: There is probably a syntax to define the original declaration, but it's going to be tricky. To define 2 template parameters as you suggest is probably the cleanest and easiest to read solution.

Answer (score 1):

You said friend `sptr<t>`,  which means it can only access the private members of sptrs to the same type. since sp2 is not a sptr( t is derived) it is not a friend. Try :

```
template< class u, class v> friend sptr<u> static_pointer_cast(const sptr<v> &sp);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Take care of formatting your answer. To format code, put 4 spaces before each line (or press the `{}` button). Your current answer hides the template parameters, since it's parsed as HTML...